# Magento 2 custom module friendly URL's

Tags: module, url-rewrite, magento-2.1.7, parameter

I have my url structured like so: "http://domain.com/**pos**t" where `post` is my module's main router url.

Then for each post I have:

```
http://domain.com/post/category/view/id/1.
and my url rewrite is  http://domain.com/post/news it works!
```

Further more I have:

```
http://domain.com/post/category/view/id/1/place/uk"
```

where **/place/uk** is another parameter just lie **id/1**

When I access this url:

http://domain.com/post/category/view/id/1/place/uk It Works !

Now here is where the problem lies using the url rewrites with `/place/uk` appended it does not work.
When I access this url: http://domain.com/post/news/place/uk it goes to 404.

Can anyone help with the above?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi there, did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @David Wilkinson No I've ditch the idea of mixing url rewrite with routes, I am handling everything within router.